# ANTLR4 throw exception and exit if any error occurs using java

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am having custom function written like this.`Functionconcat(Functionadd(1,2),1)`.

Below is the grammer I am using.
Now I have changed the grammer it is working and checking the return type for param if function exists:

```
grammar FunctionGrammer;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ; 

expr : add;
string : 'Functionadd(' INT ',' INT ')' ;
add : 'Functionadd(' INT ',' INT ')' ;
concat : 'Functionconcat(' (string|INT )','INT ')';
```

Below is the test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        CodePointCharStream input = CharStreams.fromString("Functionconcat(Functionadd(m,2),1)");
        FunctionGrammerLexer lexer = new FunctionGrammerLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        FunctionGrammerParser parser = new FunctionGrammerParser(tokenStream);
        parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());
        ParseTree tree = parser.concat();
        FunctionCompilerImpl visitor = new FunctionCompilerImpl();
        visitor.visit(tree);
    } catch (ParseCancellationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

It is throwing exception but how can I give meaningful exception like parameter/parameter datatype mismatch exception or function name mismatch exception.

visitor impl:

```
public class FunctionCompilerImpl extends FunctionGrammerBaseVisitor<String>{



    @Override
    public String visitConcat(FunctionGrammerParser.ConcatContext ctx) {
        super.visitConcat(ctx);
        System.out.println("==================="+ctx);
        return null;
    }

}
```

But vistor is not printing `System.out.println("==================="+ctx);`.

Comment: Because `visitConcat(FunctionGrammerParser.ConcatContext ctx)` method is never invoked. `visit(ParseTree tree)` is called instead. You've already asked this question before. Check out your previous question.

Comment: Thank you!! As you said I have implemented BailErrorStrategy for throwing exception but how can I give more meaningful information. As BailErrorStrategy generated exception won't have any message regarding error occurred by default.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. `BailErrorStrategy` is used to notify about an exception occured at the *parsing* phase. In your case, what you're trying to do, you have to traverse the tree *after* the prasing has completed and verify if what's been parsed meets the requirements. Use the `ctx` passed into the `visitConcat` method to get data you want to validate (functions, parameters, etc), compare it with the desired result and *manually* throw an exception (using the `throw` keyword) if something is wrong.